# Twilio Reserved Words With Hashtag/Pound

Tags: sms, keyword, twilio, hashtag, reserved-words

I am building a text message response system using Twilio and I am trying to find some clarification. From the documentation available the following are reserved words.

- STOP
- UNSUBSCRIBE
- CANCEL
- QUIT
- START
- YES
- HELP

I have coded a routine to look at the received text message to look for `#HELP` using the following regular expression.

```
^#[h|H][e|E][l|L][p|P]$
```

Since the reserved words do not have a # in front of them, why is Twilio intercepting it as a reserved word?

Also if anyone knows of other reserved words not in my list, would you please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

This definitely sounds like a bug. I've put in an issue for our engineering team to take a look. Would love to send you a shirt for catching this. Could you drop me an e-mail: ricky@twilio.com?

Here is some additional information on [reserved words](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-stop-block-and-cancel-aka-sms-filtering?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon).